# Update index values extremely slow on MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I have three tables, one is in database `db1` and two are in database `db2`, all on the same MySQL server:

```
CREATE TABLE `db1`.`user` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password_hash` varchar(71) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `registration_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `registration_hash` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `public` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `show_name` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `db2`.`ref` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `db2`.`combination` (
  `ref_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `arbitrary_number` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`figurine_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `combination_user` (`user_id`),
  KEY `combination_number` (`user_id`,`arbitrary_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `combination_ref` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_id`) REFERENCES `ref` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `combination_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `db1`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table `db1`.`user` has around 600 records, the table `db2`.`ref` has around 800 records and the table `db2`.`combination` has around 300K records.

Now using Perl and DBD::mysql I perform the following query:

```
UPDATE `db1`.`user` SET `id` = (`id` + 1000)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

However, this query always stops mentioning the connection to the MySQL server was lost. Also executing this same query via PhpMyAdmin results in a timeout. Somehow the query just takes a very long time to execute. I guess it comes because all the foreign key values need to be updated.

Setting `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` variable to `OFF` will not update the `user_id` column in the `db.combination` table, which do need to be updated.

I have also tried to manipulate the different timeouts (as suggested all over the internet), like this:

```
SET SESSION net_read_timeout=3000;
SET SESSION net_write_timeout=3000;
SET SESSION wait_timeout=6000;
```

I have verified that the new values are actually set, by retrieving the values again. However, even with these long timeouts, the query still fails to execute and after about 30 seconds the connection to the MySQL server is again lost (while amidst executing the `UPDATE` query)

Any suggestions on how to speed up this query are more than welcome.

BTW: The PK columns have a very large integer type. I will also make this type smaller (change to `INT`). Could this type change also improve the speed significantly?

**UPDATE**
I also performed an `EXPLAIN` for the query and it mentions in the `Extra` column that the query is doing a filesort. I would have expected that due to the indexes on the table (added them, as they were not there in the first place), no filesort would take place.

Comment: There is no ORDER BY on an UPDATE statement

Comment: Why would you be adding anything to an Auto Increment column?? Once a row in that table is created, leave the `id` column well alone

Comment: In bigint(20), the number 20 represents how the data will be displayed. It does not affect the storage. The number is used to display width. BIGINT takes 8 bytes i.e. 64 bits. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 and unsigned range takes positive value. The range of unsigned is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

Comment: I need to add a number to the column to prepare for merging with another database, that has the same structure. The value that I want to add makes room for the data from the other database's tables.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know that the number just represents how the data will be displayed and does not affect the storage. That is why in a later stage I want to change the storage type to a smaller type (like INT).

Comment: `UPDATE `db1`.`user` SET `id` = (`id` + 1000)` is an indication of a poorly designed schema.  Please discuss what it does and why.

Comment: @Rick James As I mentioned in another comment I need to change the id’s to be able to merge it with other data coming from databases with the same structure. I need to prevent clashes in the ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 300K `CASCADEs` is probably the really slow part of the task.  So, let's avoid it.  (However, there may be a check the verify the resulting links; this should be not-too-slow.)

1. Disable `FOREIGN KEY` processing
2. Create new tables *without* `FOREIGN KEYs`.  new_user, new_combination.  (I don't know if new_ref is needed.)
3. Do this to populate the tables:

   ```
    INSERT INTO new_xx (user_id, ...)
        SELECT user_id + 1000, ...;
   ```
4. `ALTER TABLE new_xx ADD FOREIGN KEY ...;`  (for each xx)
5. `RENAME TABLE xx TO old_xx, new_xx TO xx;
6. `DROP TABLE old_xx;
7. Enable `FOREIGN KEY` processing